# MissingRule Exception in Snakemake

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am new to snakemake workflow management and I'm struggling to grasp how the wildcards input works. I tried to do QC of some SRR data but the snakemake is giving the "MissingRuleException error".

my *config file(config.yaml)* contain the content:

samples: sample.csv

path: /Users/path/Bioinformatics/srr_practice

*sample.csv is*

```
sample_name,fq1

A,SRR11412215

B,SRR11412216

C,SRR11412217

D,SRR11412218

E,SRR11412219
```

*Snakefile*

```
import os
import pandas as pd

configfile:"config.yaml"

samples=pd.read_csv(config["samples"], sep=",").set_index("sample_name", drop=False)


def get_fastq(wildcards):

        units=samples.loc[wildcards.sample]
fq=units["fq1"]
        return expand(os.path.join(config["path"], "{fq}.fastq.gz"), fq=fq)

rule all:

    input:

        expand(os.path.join(config["path"], "fastq_output/{sample}.fastqc.html"),sample=samples["fq1"].to_list()),
        expand(os.path.join(config["path"], "fastq_output/{sample}_fastqc.zip"), sample=samples["fq1"].to_list())

rule fastq:

    input:

            get_fastq,
    output:

            zip=os.path.join(config["path"], "fastq_output/{wildcards.sample_name}_fastqc.zip"),
                html=os.path.join(config["path"], "fastq_output/{wildcards.sample_name}_fastqc.html")

    wrapper:
            "0.78.0/bio/fastqc"
```

snakemake -np Snakefile

**Error**
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce Snakefile (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By issues command `snakemake -np Snakefile` you are asking snakemake to produce `Snakefile`, and it doesn't know how to do it.

If your file is named `Snakefile`, there is no need to specify its name, if it has a different name then you can specify it using `-s` option. So right now, running `snakemake -n` should be sufficient to show you what snakemake would run.